# SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(255 , 0 , 0 , 255); not set continue open window in black color Using Visual Studio 10

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I just used SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(ren, 255,0,0,255);

for SDL_Rect rec but not changed color the window is rendered in black color im using SDL_RenderPresent(ren);

Need used anything more? may be SDL_RenderCopy?

Anybody know what happnned?

```
#include "game.h"

Game::Game(){
    SDL_Init(0);
    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(800, 600, 0, &win, &ren);
    SDL_SetWindowTitle(win, "Game-SDL2");
    running=true;
    count=0;
    loop();
}

Game::~Game(){
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(ren);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
    SDL_Quit();

}

void Game::loop(){
    while(running){

      lastFrame = SDL_GetTicks();
      int static lastTime;
      if (lastFrame >= (lastTime+1000))
      {
         lastTime=lastFrame;  
         frameCount=0;
         count++;
      }

      render();
      input();
      update();

      if (count > 3) running=false;

    }
}

void Game::render(){

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(ren, 255, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_Rect rect;
    rect.x, rect.y=0;
    rect.w=800;
    rect.h=600;
    SDL_RenderFillRect(ren, &rect);

    frameCount++;
    int timerFPS = SDL_GetTicks()-lastFrame;
    if (timerFPS > (1000/60)){
        SDL_Delay((1000/60)-timerFPS);
    }

        SDL_RenderPresent(ren, &rect);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

well i just put

SDL_RenderClear(ren);

and Worked??? appear red but i changed dimensions of rectangle rect and no change is like size if window 800x600 always red but i think the correct is set color to rectangle and not for all window

May be not solution yet